# install centos on virtualbox, your partition is less than 4671mb

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, centos

I am trying to install CentOS under my VirtualBox but keep on getting this error:

"The following errors occured with your partition: 
Your / partition is less thean 4671 MB which is lower that recommended normal CentOS install."

I am booting from a live DVD and have a 8GB disk created in virtualBox.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: net install seems to work better since I can choose 'desktop' install which needs less than 4671 mb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just ran into the same issue. I was using a dynamic hard drive and I changed it to fixed which allowed CentOS to install.

Not sure why it doesn't like dynamic hard drives. Hope this helps!